# What's this submerged, Pond Lily-like plant that propagates sideways called, or what are similar plants"

Tags: identification, water

I ran into a picture of an aquarium that I plan on buying, and it contains a type of plant that I've never seen before. I really like it. Does anyone know what it is, or can anyone recommend a similar plant to me?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure its Hydrocotile verticillata, sometimes commonly known as Money Plant - if you want to know about other plants suitable for aquariums, just look up 'aquarium plants', or 'aquatic plants suitable for aquariums'. And don't forget that some plants won't grow in warm aquariums (for tropical fish) and others won't grow too well in cold water ones.

Answer (score 0):

This is penny grass plant and can live in water and also in soil.

Comment: Hi Ann, welcome to the site. You can improve your answer by adding a photo or a link from a website. Then users can see for themselves that this is the right answer